# NetSuite Custom Module entry point error?

Tags: deployment, module, netsuite, suitescript

I have a simple custom module which posts messages to a server-side Suitelet.

```js
/**
 * test_app_client_module.js
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType ClientScript
 * @NModuleScope SameAccount
 */

define(['N/ui/message'], function(message) {

    var exports = {};

    function showMessage(messageObject) {
        message.create(messageObject).show();
    };
    
    exports.showMessage = showMessage;

    return exports;

});
```

This module functions properly when used with `form.ClientScriptModulePath` and invoked from a file cabinet, excluding `@NScriptType`.

However, if I attempt to create a script record to define this module in a remote function, I get the following error.

**SuiteScript 2.0 entry point scripts must implement one script type function.**

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you create a module you don't need to specify the @NScriptType. A module is a file that is called in a script(suitelet, clinet etc or in a module) using define or require.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message states, you haven't implemented an entry point function. All Script modules need at least one entry point.

Add an empty `pageInit` function to your module.

```
exports.pageInit = function () {}
```